# How to switch the position of values in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I need some help in switching the position of the confusion matrix as shown in the image below.[image].

The code below is the current version whereby the true positive is at the bottom right. Appreciate the help. Thanks in advance.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

#data_swn['Truth'] = data_swn['Truth'].astype(str)
cf_matrix3 = confusion_matrix(data_swn['SWN_Sentiment'], data_swn['Truth'])

cf_matrix3
```

**Ouput:**[image]

```
labels = ['True Neg','False Pos','False Neg','True Pos']
Group_percentages = ['{0:.2%}'.format(value) for value in cf_matrix1.flatten() / np.sum(cf_matrix1)]

labels = [f'{v1}\n{v2}' for v1, v2 in zip(labels,Group_percentages)]
labels = np.asarray(labels).reshape(2,2)

ax = sns.heatmap(cf_matrix1, annot=labels, fmt='', cmap='Blues')

ax.set_title('Seaborn Confusion Matrix with labels\n\n');
ax.set_xlabel('\nPredicted Values')
ax.set_ylabel('Actual Values ');

## Ticket labels - List must be in alphabetical order
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(['False','True'])
ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(['False','True'])

## Display the visualization of the Confusion Matrix.
plt.show()
```

**Ouput:**[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the best way is to reverse your data (in both dimensions, to match the desired order) before you plot it:

```
cf_matrix1 = np.array([[836,1651], [219,3411]])
cf_matrix1 = cf_matrix1[::-1,::-1]
```

Then you also need to change your label order:

```
labels = ['True Pos', 'False Pos', 'False Neg', 'True Neg']
```

Rest of your code is the same, although you probably want to change the x- and y-labels.